# Como carregar itens do array na list box?

Tags: c++, delphi, c++-builder

Tenho uma `TCheckListBox` e quando ela é marcada guardo as opções em um Array. Preciso que, ao clicar em um botão "Listar", os elementos do Array (opções marcadas da `TCheckListBox`) sejam listados na `TListBox`.

Deve ser algo parecido com isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Para isso vamos percorrer todo `TCheckListBox` procurando os itens marcados, e vamos adicionando um a um na `TListBox`.

Segue procedimento:

```
void __fastcall frmTeste::btnTesteClick(TObject *Sender)
{
  ListBox1->Clear(); //Limpando a Lista
  for (int i = 0; i < CheckListBox1->Count; i++)
  {
    if (CheckListBox1->Checked[i]) //Para cada 1 que estiver maarcado...
      ListBox1->Items->Add(CheckListBox1->Items->Strings[i]); //...Adiciona na lista
  }
}
```

Comment: Eu tinha tentado desta maneira, mas ele não deixa eu usar a CheckListBox no evento do meu botão. Erro: Undefined symbol 'clbGabarito'. OBS: clbGabarito é a minha checklistbox.

Comment: Posta seu código na pergunta!